# Swift and Objective-C Classes With the Same Name

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am still learning how to integrate Swift code into code written in Objective C. Let's say if I name the Swift file and class the same name which already was taken by any class of Objective-C. For example,

I would create: "ViewController.swift", and have the following content:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@objc class ViewController:UIViewController {
    func swiftMethod() {
        print("It works.")
    }
}
```

There are already "ViewController.h" and "ViewController.m". And later I would try to call the Swift class in Objective-C:

```
#import <myproject-Swift.h>
...
ViewController *vc = [ViewController new];
[vc swiftMethod];
...
```

How the compiler would know which class I initiated: the class from Swift or from Objective-C?

Comment: You absolutely *want* to get into trouble? ^^

Comment: I just curious what would happen in that case since I want to understand deeper what is going on with the names after that mixture/complication appears due to the introduction of the new language for iOS (Swift).

Comment: Okay, I do understand that. Have you simply tried it out? I would not be surprised if the compiler / linker would just complain at compile time.

Comment: Actually, the compiler did not complain, that made me surprised.

Comment: Okay, in the class / file where you import myproject-Swift.h you import the ViewController.h as well?

Comment: @luk2302 you made a good point. Actually, it could be two different cases: ViewController.h imported or not. Between, this situation could happen when you have an old project written in Objective C, and you want to add the new code but written in Swift. From the project and business logic you would like to keep some classes names for the connected tasks (it is not only about ViewController) and would avoid that strange renaming like oldClassNameSwift.swift with oldClassName.h and oldClassName.m

Answer (score 8):

In the Obj-C runtime, the two classes actually have different names.  The Swift class is named `YourProject.ViewController` while the Obj-C class is named simply `ViewController`.

From Obj-C code, which class you get will depend on which header you import.

If you import both headers then it's a compiler error.

If you force both classes to have the same name, using:

```
@objc(ViewController) class ViewController: UIViewController {
}
```

then it's a linker error.

Comment: Out of curiosity: for the linker error to occur you still have to import both headers? Or does the linker error occur even without importing?

Comment: The linker error occurs regardless of which headers are imported.

Comment: Yes, if I import both headers I got a kind "Project-Swift.h:106:1: Duplicate interface definition for class 'ViewController'"