# Two files with same name

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have two files in my project. One file is in a third-party Objective-C library and other is in my project.

[image]

Here **DSGHappiness** is a third-party library.

Q: How to solve this situation?

Comment: Did you see any error? Please post the error

Comment: No! I didn't get any error, but if I use `User` class then the compiler assumes that I am using it from `User.swift` class but instead I want to use it from `User.h` & `User.m` class.

Comment: Is your project in Swift?

Comment: Yes. The project is in Swift.

Comment: This might help [you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569580/swift-and-objective-c-classes-with-the-same-name)

Comment: Well, I am not getting any error. And in Swift, you do not import as the objc file is already imported in the Bridging Header file.

Comment: Can you not rename your class file leaving the third party as it is? Is this an issue.

Comment: Well, I can rename the third party file as well but wanted to check if there is a way to solve this.

Comment: Adding the module name as prefix is a possible solution: YourApp.User should give yours, and DSGHappiness.User should give the other one.